# In the state of Maryland, are there codes governing apartment building garage doors

Tags: negligence, reference-request, maryland

I haven't been able to find anything on this particular issue. Are there safety regulations governing the type, maintenance, operation, etc. of garage doors in the state of Maryland for condos/apartments?

It would seem there probably should be some law governing necessary postings, regular maintenance, etc. to guarantee safe operation of an apartment garage. A reference would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes probably. If you are not the owner, why not contact your municipality?

http://www.choosecambridge.com/index.php/extensions/dept-public-works/building-safety-services/